# html2pdf - get page content inside IEventHandler implementation

Tags: itext, html2pdf

I need to have two different headers in my pdf generated using html2pdf from iText.

Currently I'm 'printing' the headers by using a implemetation of `IEventHandler`. Like this:

```
public virtual void HandleEvent(Event @event)
    {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();

        int pageNumber = pdf.GetPageNumber(page);
        Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();

        // Creates drawing canvas
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pageSize);

        try
        {
                if (typeof(Paragraph) == element.GetType()) // This is an IElement object
                {
                    Paragraph p = (Paragraph)element;

                    if (p.GetChildren().Count > 0)
                    {
                        p.SetWidth(pageSize.GetWidth() - iLeftMargin - iRightMargin).SetMarginLeft(iLeftMargin);
                        canvas.Add(p);
                    }
                }

            canvas.Close();
            pdfCanvas.Release();
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Now I need to check if the current page has a specific text (or anything) so I can change the text inside my `element` object and then print a different header.

It would be really nice if the `TagWorker` get processed alogside `IEventHandler`, but it is sequential, and I can't know when i need to change the text in my header.

Comment: Hi, could you add a self-contained minimal code sample to reproduce, with the HTML that features an example of a text piece you want to differentiate your logic upon? You could get page content and parse it, or you could overload the tag worker and set some temporary custom keys in your PDF page object. It depends a bit on the input data and more precise description of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @AlexeySubach I'm using custom tags also, is there a way to get the page number of the document when processing those tags? That would give me the information to solve my problem. If not, I will try to make that self-contained code to exmplain better my needs.

Comment: When you process tags with `tag workers`, there no way to access page number just yet. The pipeline looks as follows: HTML tags -> tag workers -> layout elements -> layout renderers -> draw on page. You can access page number info starting from `layout renderers` level